# Jquery validation - Error on adding rules to input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement Jquery validation with http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation :

**My design plan:**

- My **input** element:

  ```
  <form action="submit.php" id="form_id">
    <input type="text" class="val-req" id="my_input" name="myval" />
    <input type="button" onclick="validate_form('form_id', function() { $('#form_id').submit(); })" />
    <span id="val-msg" class="my_input"></span>
  </form>
  ```
- Then, on dom ready:

  ```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.val-req').rules('add', {required:true});
                     });
  ```
- Validate method:

  ```
   function validate_form(form_id, callback) {
         var form = $('#'+form_id);
         $('.val-req').each(function() {$(this).rules('add', {required:true});});
         $(form).validate({
                  errorElement: "span",
                  errorClass:   "val-error",
                  validClass:   "val-valid",
                  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                                        $('#val-msg.'+$(element).attr('id')).innerHTML(error.html());
                                 },
                  submitHandler: callback
         });
   }
  ```

As per my expectations, it should display error message in the place holder span in the form.

But, **Problem**

> **Error on Chrome-Console**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

It is also giving error on other browsers.
Then, I tried to figure-out the problem and found:

```
 $('.val-req').rules('add', {required:true});   # This is causing the error
```

As, per my understanding and documentation -> This should be correct.

Why would this cause the TypeError and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: FYI, I have started a discussion about this question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133057/153691).

Comment: There has been a confusion - that a typo resolved the issue. I deny that. I made the typo while writing the question, which was later corrected - but that was not the issue at all.

Comment: The problem is still persisting and I have absolutely no clue what's wrong with my implementation.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks for the effort sir. Stackoverflow is really a valuable community !

Comment: No problem--I have added an answer that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 18):

You have to add the rules after you call the validate plugin in the form element:

```
$("form").validate()
$(yourElement).rules("add", {...})
```

Comment: Just had the same problem, forgot to $("#formid").validate()

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is more complicated than it needs to be. You should just have to call `validate` on document ready (assuming your form exists on document ready):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".val-req").addClass("required");
    $("#form_id").validate({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "val-error",
        validClass: "val-valid",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#val-msg.' + $(element).attr('id')).html(error.html());
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4vDGM/

You could also just add a class of `required` to required elements instead of adding them via JavaScript.

Another thing you could do is add rules in the rules object of `validate`'s options:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_id").validate({
        rules: {
            myval: "required"
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "val-error",
        validClass: "val-valid",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#val-msg.' + $(element).attr('id')).html(error.html());
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GsXnJ/

Comment: Hm, but I have a custom submit method that submit values with ajax onclick event of a div button.
Plus I don't want `require` class on my inputs, since I want it to be val-req, and similarly val-email and so on !

Comment: I can-not add inline rules in the validation method, since same code will be used to validate 20 forms with n number of fields. If I do that it would actually defeat the purpose.

Comment: @YugalJindle: Ah, okay. In that case you could just add an event handler for "click" on the button and submit the form that way.

Comment: I mean I have different forms with different submitting logics, but I will pass those submit methods as callback to this `validate_form` method, and want to keep the validation independent of the forms themselves.

Comment: I am looking to generalize the validation for multiple forms, that's why I need that dynamism.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to modify the rules on a form that already had validation being set up, but i found my $(document).ready(...) code was executing before the main form validation was set up, so adding a short setTimeout cured this issue for me - e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(yourElement).rules("add", {...})
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the method delegate(), which does not check whether a validator exists:

```
function delegate(event) {
  var validator = $.data(this[0].form, "validator"),
  eventType = "on" + event.type.replace(/^validate/, "");
  // this fixes handling the deleted validator:
  if (!validator) return;
  validator.settings[eventType] && validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0], event);
}
```

I was searching for a solution and found it in a blog post.

Source: http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/fixing-jquery-validation-with-changing-validators/